# Logarithm discontinuous even though domain is analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis

I tried to check if $f(z)=\log(z)$ returns to its original value if $z$ moves in an analytic domain such as $|z+1|= 1-h$ where $0<h<1$. So, the path can be parameterized as $z(\theta)=-1+(1-h)e^{i\theta}$ where $\theta$ goes from $0$ to $2\pi$. Initially, when $\theta=0,\; f(z(0))=\log(-1)$ and as $\theta \to 2\pi, f(z(\theta)) \to \log(-1+(1-h)e^{i2\pi})=\log(-he^{i2\pi})=\log(-h)+2\pi i$. But I expected it to return to its original value as $\log(z)$ is analytic in this domain and the curve doesn't pass through any branch point or branch cut. Please tell me where I went wrong. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: How do you define $\log(z)$?

Comment: How did you check? Most calculators will use the main branch of the logarithm, no matter what domain you imagined. They don't choose a logarithm dynamically to fit your needs.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Any branch of $\log$ with branch cut running from $0$ to $\infty$?

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos I only checked the continuity of $\log$ as I have shown above.

Comment: Oh, I just saw your picture and thought you used a calculator. In that case, keep in mind that $e^{2\pi\mathrm i}=e^0$, so $\log e^{2\pi\mathrm i}=\log e^0=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The error lies in the equality $\log(-he^{2\pi i})=\log(-h)+2\pi i$. Actually,$$he^{2\pi i}=h\implies\log(-he^{2\pi i})=\log(-h).$$

Comment: Shouldn't the phase factor disappear as $z$ comes back to its original value?

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't know what “phase factor” means.

Comment: I didn't mean to actually evaluate $\log(-he^{2\pi i})$. What I meant was, as $\theta \to 2\pi, \log(z) \to \log(-h)+2\pi i$

Comment: Do you have some good reason to assume that that's so? I see none.

Comment: Okay, perhaps I'm wrong. Could you please show how $\log$ would return to its original value as $\theta \to 2\pi$?

Comment: Because $\log$ is a function and a function cannot take two distinct values at the same point. In particular, $\log(-h)$ is a single number, not two numbers. If your $\log$ function is $\log(z)=\log(|z|)+i\operatorname{arg}(z)$, where $\operatorname{arg}(z)$ is the only argument of $z$ in $(0,2\pi)$, then $\log(-h)=\log|h|+\pi i$.